Flutter: RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions error in Dialog with GridView
I'm working on a Flutter application where I have a filter button that opens a dialog containing various sorting and filtering options. The dialog includes a GridView.builder to display filter options. However, when I run the app, I encounter the following error:
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.
Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require instantiating every child of the viewport, which defeats the point of viewports being lazy.
If you are merely trying to shrink-wrap the viewport in the main axis direction, consider a RenderShrinkWrappingViewport render object (ShrinkWrappingViewport widget), which achieves that effect without implementing the intrinsic dimension API.)

Here is the code I am using:
import 'package:SolidCheck/core/constants/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final GlobalKey _buttonKey = GlobalKey();

Widget buildFilter(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    height: 50.0,
    width: 50.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: AppColors.kGreyColor.withOpacity(0.2),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: IconButton(
        key: _buttonKey,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.tune_outlined),
        onPressed: () {
          _showOptionsDialog(context);
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}

void _showOptionsDialog(BuildContext context) {
  final filterOptions = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'];

  showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Options'),
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: AppColors.kBlueColor,
              child: const ListTile(
                title: Text('Sort By:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Date Created - Newest First'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Date Created - Oldest First'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Alphabetical (A-Z)'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Alphabetical (Z-A)'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            Container(
              color: AppColors.kBlueColor,
              child: const ListTile(
                title: Text('Filter:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Status'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              child: GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                ),
                itemCount: filterOptions.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(filterOptions[index]),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Organization'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Close'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}

I've tried using a SingleChildScrollView but encountered the same error. How can I resolve this issue to correctly display the dialog with the GridView inside it?


most likely you need LimitedBox - the docs say: "A box that limits its size only when it's unconstrained.
If this widget's maximum width is unconstrained then its child's width is limited to maxWidth. Similarly, if this widget's maximum height is unconstrained then its child's height is limited to maxHeight."

It is somewhat known issue, you need to use a explicit width for your Listview
return AlertDialog(
  title: const Text('Options'),
  content: SizedBox(
    width: 400.0,
    child: GridView(
...

